# Phrase for "Lowering the points/grade on exam"

Tags: phrase-requests

Assume that you had an exam.
The teacher returned the exam and gave you *negative* points on several questions.
This "lowering of the grade of the exam" seems unjustified to you.
Which expression exists for saying "unjustifiably lowered the grade on several sub-questions" ?

Comment: You were "marked down" on several questions.  Though the term does not imply either "negative" points or lack of justification.

Comment: You were DownVoted! Oh, wait.....

Comment: Does “giving you negative points,” mean that the question should have been worth 10 points [out of 100] (eg,1 out of 10 total, equally valued questions) but the teacher took off 12 points for it instead? In that case, the error is simply one of math. If s/he wrote “minus 10 ” next to the answer then s/he’s simply starting at a perfect score & subtracting the value of the missed questions from the total possible to arrive at your grade, which is not “giving you negative points.” If one of your correct answers was marked as incorrect, then the teacher simply “made a mistake grading your test.”

Comment: In both the "math error" & the "correct answer marked as incorrect" examples mentioned in my earlier comment, you could tell the teacher: "Hey, you took too many points off my test." or "You made a mistake grading my test."  Assuming that s/he is not "out to get" either you or the whole class, the problem will be easily resolved. If s/he insists that it's not a math error in the above scenario, just ask the teacher to start at zero and **add** 12 points for each of your correct answers to arrive at your grade & you might even end-up ahead thanks to your teacher's feeble math skills!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest, ***hard grading*** [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/translate/french-english/saquer)

*This **hard grading** on several sub-questions on the exam seems unjustified to me*.

> grade hard: (*Chiefly AmEng*) *Inf.* to grade severely [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/grade%20hard)

Comment: As far as I know, a *hard-grader* is a tough teacher who demands that students apply themselves. He doesn't give easy grades. But that in no way implies unfairness. In fact, diligent students tend to love hard-graders, especially in the mid- and long-term. I'm not saying your answer doesn't work, just noting the lack of the *unfairness* connotations required in OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most idiomatic way is to use **grade down** (or **mark down**, as pointed out by @HotLicks):

> **grade down**: to give someone a lower rank or score, usually with respect to something evaluated:
>
> *The teacher graded me down on my English test because of my terrible penmanship.*

([TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/grade))

> **mark down**: to give a student a **lower mark** for their work for a particular reason
>
> *They’ll mark you down for poor spelling.*

([Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/mark-down))

It doesn't carry the connotations of unfairness, but since a phrase is OK you could say someone was **unfairly graded down**.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify if the exam was of a multiple-choice format, but if it was, then your teacher may have been applying a formula similar to that used by the [SAT](https://sat.collegeboard.org/scores/how-sat-is-scored) test:

- +1 point for a correct answer
- -0.25 point for an incorrect answer
- 0 point for a blank answer

The negative points for incorrect answers are supposed to compensate for the statistical likelihood of getting correct answers by guessing.  Most test-takers call it a "guessing penalty" but SAT itself prefers to call it a "wrong answer penalty."

This [link](http://www.batesville.k12.in.us/physics/calcnet/Intro/guessing_penalty.htm) gives examples of how it works.